# How to make div size independent from containing text?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, grid-layout

I tried to make a simple UI using flexbox and grid layout: https://codepen.io/antonpotapovdev/pen/XWpgEJQ

Now, if the `display` text gets too long, the whole form stretches to contain it. I could set `width` for the display explicitly, which prevents stretching, but it means that in the future if I want to add more columns with buttons (or even add them dynamically), I will also have to change `width`. It would be perfect if the `display` grows as columns are added, but ignores size of the inner text, and long text becomes scrollable.

Comment: `width: 0;
    min-width: 100%` to the text

Comment: If you are using grid I don't think you will need flexbox. Although grid can be a bit difficult to learn when first starting. If you have a specific question or layout you need to be done in grid, I would ask that.